# Lightning Async Action calls versus JS Promises

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

The Lightning Developer Guide states:

> All the action calls are asynchronous and run in
>   batches.

If this is the case, does the framework have any concept resembling JavaScript promises?

It seems that the `aura:doneWaiting` event might fulfill that role, but I'm not clear on if there is a need to pass some specific event to the action, or if it will just handle server responses in the component's scope.

I'm kicking of an action call (which retrieves a list of Contacts) on component init, then am attempting to pass the result to the component in a custom render function. Because of the async nature of the action, my component is rendering before the call successfully returns. Is `aura:doneWaiting` the way to go here?

**Updated:**
I may be approaching this the wrong way and can potentially leverage how the framework handles data binding, and rerendering when underlying data changes. Will post a definitive answer if I come across one. I'd still be interested to know if comparing `aura:doneWaiting` to JavaScript promises is appropriate or not.

Comment: Have you tried loading your contacts in a callback using `cmp.set("v.contacts", response.getReturnValue());` instead? This example shows you how: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one_demo_load.htm

Comment: This is what I used in my question update above. Where things went awry was the fact that I was using this in a custom render function. When I moved this to a custom RErender it works because this rerender seems to fire when the underlying data actually loads.

Comment: What if have ten functions that call a common function?  The common function is asynchronous.  You want to do something (something different in each case) when the asynchronous function completes.  /  You could pass a callback function to the common function, and have it execute that function when it finishes.  Or you could say myAsynchFunction().then(...)  /  The latter would be easier to read and understand.  /  I looked at the cmp.set example mentioned.  It does what you want to do in the callback of the asynch function.

Comment: unclear what is the matter, is the purpose to get rid of telescopic callbacks? Does remote actions batching give any trouble? to disable batching use 'action.setBackground();' I would refrain using 'doneWaiting', this thingy is good for showing/hiding spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/understanding-system-events-lightning-components-part-2.html) article

> When we make an Apex call using $A.enqueueAction(), the framework
>   fires:
>
> waiting event to allow us to show visual indication like “waiting..”
>   or a “spinner” to the user
>
> **doneWaiting** event is triggered to allow us to hide any visual
>   indication
>
> **valueChange** is fired ONLY IF the callback updates some value
>
> **rerender** if a value is changed
>
> **doneRendering** is eventually called
>
> [image]
>
> **Things To Note:**
>
> 1. **waiting** and **doneWaiting** are always fired whenever we use  $A.enqueueAction()
> 2. However **valueChange**, **rerender** and **doneRendering** are only
>      fired if our business logic changes some attribute value of the
>      component.

PS: You can use rerender() in your custom renderer to write some logic.